# iOS first launch after update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, updates, launch

Upon the first launch of my app, i have used NSUser defaults to show an intro of my app.

However, once an update has been issued and installed, i want to show a whats new page on the first launch after update. My issue is that NS user defaults does not reset and everyone will have different launch counts.

I could use this code to work out the software version...

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]]isEqualToString:@"Version 1.0"])
{
// first launch code here
}
```

...but how could i then only get the whats new page to appear on the first launch after update rather than every launch?

If any code is required, it would need to be in Objective C as I have not yet begun developing in swift. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to store a boolean value like `"hasShowedUpatePopupForVersionXX"`. 
Don't forget to set it to `YES` in case of new installs

```
//check if popup has been shown 
 if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"hasShowedUpatePopupForVersionXX"]) {
     // Set the value to YES   
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@YES forKey:@"hasShowedUpatePopupForVersionXX"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Would you mind providing an example as i am very new to development and haven't yet set boolean values in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I updated with sample code. Don't forget to use a condition to check for startup screen

Comment: I would store the version number instead so that I don't have to create a new key every time a new version comes out.

Answer (score 3):

Do a version check of your app and store the current version in NSUserDefaults. Then on launch check to make sure that value matches the current value. If it doesn't, display the content you wish to display then save the NSUserDefaults key to the new value. I wouldn't store a Bool value and would rather store the current version of your app.

How to get the current version

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Comment: It does sounds more clever, but then you can't push specific code for migration, and minor updates (small bug fixes) would trigger the update screen, which might not be appropriate.

Comment: ? Why would this not work for a specific build? The only thing in question is the current version. Display the current changes for the current version and everything else will obviously be in the past. And no... all you have to do is check the version number and decipher major vs minor builds. If the version number is correctly assigned this is easy (1.x vs 1.1 vs 1.1.1 and so on). Adding a Bool value for every single update would add a lot of clutter and unnecessary fields to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Surely i could just load a set view with the appropriate info every time the app loads after it is updated. This could always be the same view as I can change the info every update. How could I load this view in an iF statement using the above code? Sorry  if this is a bit stupid but I'm a little confused about how to implement the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Using the above codes, I have created a fully working section of code which finds the App version.

If the app version in the NSUserdefaults is not the same, it will complete the segue and update the NSUserdefaults so that it does not run again until the app Updates.

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

NSLog(@"App Version is %@",version);

if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]]isEqualToString:@"Version 1.0"])
{
    //check if popup has been shown
    if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"appVersion"] isEqualToString:version]) {
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showUpdate" sender:self];
        // Set the value to YES
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:version forKey:@"appVersion"];
    }
```